# heresy on Purim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

On Purim we're supposed to engage in מִשְׁלוֹחַ מִנוּת, the sending of heresy to our fellow Jews. What are some pieces of heretical literature that are appropriate for sending on Purim? Or ones you'd like to receive?

---

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/301.

Comment: LOL!  How about a serious question - how far can you go with "Purim Torah"? Can you go so far as to state actual heresy?

Comment: And now R'Seth's asked that as a separate question: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6306.

Comment: Whatever you do, just make sure to include two of them; after all, halachah requires שני מינים.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55900/5323

Comment: I'm considering writing an answer to this along the lines of "Megilat Esther, which is heretical in that it (and its heroes) refuse to ascribe anything to God," but I'm not sure if that'd be a) [excessively sacreligious](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1666977543328745&set=a.528802287146282.138677.100000495466416&type=3&theater), or b) [too serious](https://www.amazon.com/Vanishing-Jew-Wake-Up-Call-Esther/dp/1543128130/ref=pd_zg_rss_nr_b_12540_6).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you should do is combine this with matanos la'evyonim, by sending to poor people. That way you're making the heretical declaration (at least according to Turnus Rufus, Bava Basra 10a) that even though Hashem isn't providing for them, you are.

Answer (score 13):

Yesterday (on *Shabas parashas Zachor, erev Purim*), I asked a local rabbi a similar question, how one can best fulfill the obligation of *mishloach minus*. He said via the Internet.

Comment: Indeed, the Internet provides for very efficient distribution of heresy, but can one fulfill this Mitzva without hand-delivery?

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to point, that despite the custom to send *manos* via a *shliah*, sending heresy could be done only by the sender himself. Because, there is no shliah ledvar aveira.

Answer (score 12):

All I can do is tell you the following true story:

When Rabbi Meir Leibush Malbim arrived in Bucharest as its chief rabbi (and I believe chief rabbi of all Romania), the city's "progressive" Jewish population was excited that a Hebrew grammarian and Biblical thinker would take the post. They were quite dismayed to find that despite Rabbi Malbim's outside-the-box Bible commentary, his ritual observances were quite traditional. One year they sent him mishloach manos containing pork and crabs, with a note:

> We, the Enlightened population of Bucharest, hereby send our choicest delicacies to our esteemed chief rabbi.

Rabbi Malbim responded by sending a small copy of a portrait of himself:

> Gentleman, thanks for the picture of you; here's one of me.