# What was the attitude of Rabbonim regarding Purim Torah?

Tags: minhag, torah-study, purim

Purim Torah seems to be a two sided concept. On one hand, many people do it for many years (for example, [Maseches Purim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/37448) was published in 1871).

On the other hand, it seems to be a Bizayon HaTorah (disgracing Torah) as one is making fun of Torah and its svaros (logic).

---

Did any famous Rabbonim talk about it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6306/5

Comment: Check this out: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&hilite=48420efc-7534-481a-8216-84b86951879a&st=%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA+%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D&pgnum=408

Comment: Depends what exactly is done and how. There are stories of Big Rabonim who were "Rav Purim" and gave some sort of "Purim Shpiel", but it was done without Bizayon. Rav Kook, I think, would be brought two unconnected Gemara pages and would turn them into one Sugya.

Comment: It seems that in heder it was ok https://ashreinu.app/#/player/playlist~early-years_episode~5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2008/03/purim-and-parodies-by-eliezer-brodt.html) (all brackets excluding footnotes added),

> As many other books this [i.e. Maseches Purim] to [sic] was banned, by many, most notably R. Shmuel Aboab (siman 193). Others who opposed these works were authors of Chemdas Hayomim, Beris Mateh Moshe and the Chida.[16] At some points certain versions of Mesechtas Purim were even burned![17]

(His main reference is the book *Parody in Jewish Literature*, available online [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=YbnZlHrsA-wC&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q&f=false). Rabbi Shmu'el Abuhab is [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=686&st=&pgnum=147&hilite=).)

[This website](http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/ktuv/mgilot/tklt_avrhm_mskt.html) says that Rabbi Ya'akov Yisra'el Kanievski wrote a Maseches Purim when he was young (though when it quotes Rabbi Abuhab it has the incorrect place as is obvious to whomever looks there).

More information and related links can be found [here](http://www.bhol.co.il/forum/topic.asp?whichpage=1&topic_id=2379251&forum_id=19616) and [here](http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=4113) (yes, the last one is in Yiddish, but if you just click the links given and look at the pictures you can probably figure it out without knowing Yiddish).

Answer (score 3):

The Chida writes in his Maagal Tov that when he was in Amsterdam he was by their Seudas Purim. He quotes the Purim Torah. It is obvious which on e he liked and which one he found cheap. He referred to the first one who stood up as a Letz that said a Shiur Meluchlach. The second one who got up, was a Talmud Chacham, and said a Pilpul, albeit a cute one.

Comment: Hi HaLeiVi and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for this answer, hope to see you around the site.

Answer (score 3):

I heard from A Talmid of Rav aharon Kotler ZTL, that in Lakewood Yeshivah, The senior bochurim would present Rav Aharon Kotler with a deep "lomdis" chaburah, of Purim torah. Sometimes if the Purim - Torah said included making fun of torah ideas, Rav Aharon would say Nuuuu Sha Sha!! and go on to the next bochur's torah.

I Also heard from Rav Hillel Zaks ZTL, That when he was a student in Bais Medrash Elyon, under Rav HaRav Reuven zt"l, One Purim he told HaRav Reuven zt"l that he wants to tell him a purim torah.
Rav Reuven allowed him to say it and he began with citing a Rambam and asked 5 questions on it from 5 different gemarahs, and then quoted a few more gemarahs and rishonim and achronim which he used to answer the questions.
When he finished HaRav Reuven Grozovsky zt"l asked him why he had called it a Purim torah, as it was an amazing piece of Torah?

Rav Zaks ZTL Answered, "Yes all of it was truly amazing -  except for the first Rambam which does not exist and I had made it up on my own".