# Mocking God- sources

Tags: theology

Is there an issur for a Jew to mock God by means of satire or a joke? is joking about God halahcically distinct from "birkas hashem," (cursing God) which is prohibited even to Bnei Noach (per Sanhedrin 59b)? The only source I can think of that directly addresses scoffers is Tehillim 1:1 ובמושב לצים לא ישב. Can you think of any others, be they biblical or rabbinic?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6306/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14538/759

Comment: Kal Vechomer! If cursing is assur, to make leitzanus is muttar? Not everything needs to be source based, ל"ל קרא,סברא הוא!

Comment: Mefaresh- perhaps so. But if an explicit source does exist, I'd love to see it.

Comment: what do you mean by an "issur"? one of the 613 mitzvot?

Comment: I think 'mock' can use a clarification in this question. You mean actually make fun of Him? Like the type joke an atheist might say? Or mock in a way which is obviously a joke, where the listeners understand the joke in no way is meant to mean a serious disregard or disapproval?

Answer (score 1):

The גמרא says in סנהדרין דף סג עמוד ב:

> אמר רב נחמן כל ליצנותא אסירא חוץ מליצנותא דעבודת כוכבים דשריא
>
> All mockery is forbidden other than that of idol worship.

So, there is a general prohibition on leitzanus, even without referencing God. I don't think you will be able to find any sources explicitly referring to ליצנות of God, as all ליצנות is forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

Most Jews who mock God are mocking the Jewish version thereof, I.e. Judaism.

This seems more to fall into the category of mah ha'avodah ha'zos lachem than birchas Hashem.

Humour is a good way of unravelling society.