# Origin of משלוח מנות

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In which part of the Persian Kingdom did the concept of משלוח מנות originate?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6305/5323

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/834/limited-purim-torah-questions . I think you could make this more general by saying "which part of the Persian Kingdom originated משלוח מנות" or something similar, rather than presuming an answer that narrows it down so much.

Comment: @yishai, while I think my answer is a good pun, I'm not heavily invested in the question. If my revision doesn't really take off, I'm not going to protest closure.

Answer (score 1):

The Megillah says (9:19):

> עַל-כֵּן הַיְּהוּדִים הפרוזים (הַפְּרָזִים), הַיֹּשְׁבִים בְּעָרֵי הַפְּרָזוֹת--עֹשִׂים אֵת יוֹם אַרְבָּעָה עָשָׂר לְחֹדֶשׁ אֲדָר, 
>   שִׂמְחָה וּמִשְׁתֶּה וְיוֹם טוֹב; וּמִשְׁלֹחַ מָנוֹת, אִישׁ לְרֵעֵהוּ.
>
> Therefore do the Jews of Paris, that dwell in the Parisian towns (suburbs), make the fourteenth day of the month Adar a day of gladness and feasting, and a good day, and of sending portions one to another.