# Was the universe created with English?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> לזאת יקרא אשה, כי מאיש לוקחה זאת -  מכאן שניתנה התורה בלשון הקודש. רבי פנחס ורבי חלקיה בשם רבי סימון אמרי: כשם שניתנה תורה בלשון הקודש, כך נברא העולם בלשון הקודש, שמעת מימיך אומר גיני גיניא?! אנתרופי אנתרופא?! גברא גברתא?! אלא, איש ואשה. למה? שהלשון הזה נופל על הלשון הזה:
>
> "To this shall be called "ishah," for from "ish" was this taken; from here we can infer that the Torah was given in Hebrew. R' Pinchas and R' Chilkiah said in the name of R' Simon: just as the Torah was given in Hebrew, so was the world created with Hebrew. Have you ever heard someone say [that a man is a] Gini [and a woman is a] Ginya? Andropei and Andropa? Gavra and Gaverta? Only Ish and Ishah. Why? Because the two words parallel each other.
>
> (Bereishis Rabbah 18:4)

This is true of English as well - man and woman. So maybe the world was created with English!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Womyn#Background I think you mean woman and werman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible that the world could have been created in English.

The majority of the world's population lives in the Northern hemisphere (See [this article](http://www.businessinsider.com/90-of-people-live-in-the-northern-hemisphere-2012-5).) If you view the earth's rotation from the top of the north pole, you'll notice that it rotates counter-clockwise meaning from left to right. Most of the world's languages are written left to right, also. You can see that most people like writing in the same direction as the Earth's rotation. (You didn't know that Australians write backwards?)

I can't quite understand why Breishit Rabbah makes this argument that it had to have been created in Hebrew, which is a language that is written from right to left. And then, to make their argument, they use Aramaic words which is also a language written from right to left!

How silly is that??? Oh, I forgot - this is a Midrash. Not everything in the Midrash needs to be accepted literally. I guess the Midrash must have been making a Purim joke, here.

Comment: That's some hardcore [mishloach minus](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6305/9682) right there. Well done.

Comment: @DonielF It's not "hardcore" at all. Had I learned this page of Gemara in high school, I would have made the same point. Of course, I probably would have been kicked out of class for being smarter than my rebbe!