# PTIJ: Should I kill my computer after installing software?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shemot 22:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=370) says that a wizard should not live.

When I buy a new computer or if I've inherited a computer and I install new software, it frequently involves a wizard to set it up or install it. What should I do with this? The software package doesn't show the wizard or mention anything about it. Otherwise, of course, I wouldn't have purchased it because I'm not supposed to trust in wizards.

But, now that I'm about to install it and the CD or the download process has begun, the wizard is now on my computer. Should I kill the entire computer? Should I kill just the software itself? What's the proper halacha, here?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: My default answer whenever I see a question about computer security and maintenance is to quote a line from the פיזמון by ר' ינקווייך titled 'Virus Alert':  "Turn off your computer and make sure it powers down,
 Drop it in a forty-three-foot hole in the ground,
 Bury it completely; rocks and boulders should be fine,
 Then burn all the clothes you may have worn any time you were online!"

Comment: Why am I seeing this in the review queue as “primarily opinion based”? Does someone not get the idea behind PTIJ?

Comment: This question came up in HNQ and took me completely by surprise. I didn't know what to expect but this was not it.

Answer (score 14):

No need. Your computer does enough murder on its own; it'll kill the wizard for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer may create more more problems than it solves. So you got rid of the Mechasheifah issue, but now you want to 'sacrifice child'? Looks like you went out of the frying pan and into the fires of Molech!

Comment: @Salmononius2 Obviously the fires are those of Sereifah of Harugei Beis Din.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Alternatively, in the spirit of [Mishloach Minus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6305/9682), say that the prohibition of Molech is intimacy with a non-Jew (Megillah 25a).

Comment: I'm at my computer now, and the comments are funnier than the answer. My computer is dying from laughter!

Comment: @DanF "My computer is dying from laughter!" So your question is moot. If we kill your computer with comedy, we don't have to worry about wizards and child sacrifice! The result is the same!

Comment: No, child sacrifice is the akeida gone wrong

Comment: @DonielF sereifah doesn't involve any flames, AFAIK.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות That’s the joke

Answer (score 5):

The installation wizard isn't really a problem, because it actually doesn't use magic. It's all just bells and whistles.

However, Linux users should be careful not to use the `file` command, because it [does use magic](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic).